# Are uninitialized pointers in objects with static storage duration initialized to NULL, or to all-zeros?

Tags: c++, standards-compliance, language-lawyer

out of curiousity and because I don't have my copy of the standard at hand right now:

Given an implementation where null pointers are not represented by an all-zeros pattern, will uninitialized pointer members of objects with static storage duration be initialized to the proper null pointer value, or to an all-zeros value?

Less standardese, more code:

```
struct foo {
    void *p;
};

foo f;
```

Given a NULL pointer representation of 0x00000001, what can I expect for the bitwise representation of f.p at the beginning of *main()*?

Comment: is it realy that hard to initialize that pointer yourself?

Comment: @Gajet: if you're writing code, no. If you're reading code, yes. Many programmers cultivate both skills ;-p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard says (8.5/4):

> To zero-initialize an object of type T
>   means:
>
> — if `T` is a scalar type, the object is set to the value 0
>   (zero), taken as an integral constant
>   expession, converted to `T`
>
> — if `T` is a non-union class type, each non-static data member and each
>   base-class subobject is zero-initialized;

So `f` is effectively initialised as `f = { (void *)0 }`, and we know from 4.10/1:

> A null pointer constant is an
>   integral constant expression
>   rvalue of integer type that evaluates
>   to zero. A null pointer constant can
>   be converted to a pointer type; the
>   result is the null pointer value of
>   that type

So you will get the correct `NULL` value.

Comment: @Heandel: No, I've expanded on that.

Comment: @Haendel: I second Oli: the standard says that `0` is a null pointer constant, guaranteed. It doesn't say that `0` is a null pointer constant only if the bitwise representation of a null pointer is the same as the bitwise representation of `0`.

Comment: @Heandel: I also second Oli. The Standard says that the value 0 is the null pointer constant- whether or not this is the bitwise null pointer constant is irrelevant.

Comment: @Heandel: It means that the bitwise representation of a null pointer is abstracted from the programmer.

Comment: @Haendel - This will make it harder for systems where NULL isn't bitwise zero, but not impossible. Possibly it will lead to larger executables if all static data has to be generated at compile time.

Comment: @Hean: in the context of pointers, yes. There is an implementation defined mapping between the literal `0` and whatever memory address is most reasonable to use as a null pointer. This is most obvious when dealing with pointer-to-members, where `0` is often actually -1.  Note that this is only true when dealing with a literal zero; `int I = 0; (void*)I;` receives no special treatment. And the mapping is only one way, converting back into an int might not yield `0` unless that's the actual representation.

Comment: @Heandel: Even integer zero isn't necessarily represented as all-zero-bits (consider that 1's complement has two zero representations).  Floating-point zero isn't necessarily all-zero-bits (IEEE-754 has two as well).  It doesn't really make sense to talk about a "zero" pointer, only a "null" pointer; and again, this doesn't necessarily have to be all-zero-bits.

Comment: I find it helpful sometimes to think of literal zeroes as representing their own numeric type, which can be promoted to any other numeric type.  The behavior of casting a LiteralZero to a pointer is not the same as casting an integer that happens to have a value of zero.  I don't know of any implementations where casting a legitimate pointer to an integral type would ever yield zero, but if casting a legitimate pointer to an integral type happened to yield zero, one could cast a non-literal integer expression that happened to evaluate to zero back into that pointer.

Answer (score 2):

To the proper null pointer value. See 8.5/5

- if T is a scalar type [and a pointer is a scalar type, see 3.9/10] the object is set to the value of 0 (zero) converted to T